# Do not change tabs on file re-open with Vim NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

This is similar to [NERDTree: open file in current window?](https://superuser.com/questions/821720/nerdtree-open-file-in-current-window) in setup, but different in intent.

Sequence of events:

1. I have a tab in Vim (v8.1) with a window that has a buffer open for a particular file.
2. I go to a different tab with NERDTree (v5.0) open in it, navigate to that file, and hit `Enter` (or `o`).
3. Vim jumps tabs to the window with the file's buffer open.

I want to change the behavior at `3`. If the file is in another tab, I want to instead reopen the file in the same tab, in my most recent non-NERDTree window. I use a number of tabs, some of them sharing views of the same individual files, for different interrelated subtasks. Getting them mixed up or lost among them is antithetical to my productivity.

I can get *close* to mitigating this annoyance by instead modifying my behavior to always hit `s` or `i` in NERDTree to split the most-recent window, but then I have to jump around my windows to close the previous non-NERDTree windows to reduce clutter (which itself becomes a hassle).

A less satisfactory mitigation would be a way to jump back to the last window I was in, similar to backtick or `Ctrl-I/O`, but instead of jumps within a window I'd have something to jump to the previous window (note that `C-w C-p` does not jump across tabs). This would at least mitigate the frustration of getting lost among my tabs.

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Comment: @filbranden Oh snap there's a vim stack exchange! Heck, I've even apparently asked a few questions there. I completely forgot about that.

But apparently flagging for a move requires noting that the question is off-topic (which best I can tell it technically isn't); do you happen to know the etiquette for that or is that a question for meta?

Comment: You can ask for moderator intervention (which you can do for your own posts) and ask them to migrate. It's ok though, I was pointing it out for future questions! I still haven't had time to check yours but will do so as soon as I can. It's definitely an interesting question!